# Validar dato correctamente en base de datos (interfaz gráfica JSwing)

Tags: java, sql, java-swing, jdbc

Estoy tratando de conectarme por primera vez con una base de datos a través de una interfaz gráfica y estoy teniendo algunos problemas ya que me gustaría validar los datos introducidos en el campo de texto

***Funcionamiento sería el siguiente:***

En la ventana indico el nombre de la empresa, al pulsar validar comprueba que esta en la base de datos, si está indica que es correcto y la empresa existe y si no se encuentra indica que no está registrada.

***Que es lo que realmente hace:***

Saca muchas ventanas y no da el resultado adecuado en la ventana, es decir dice que no está la empresa en BD, aunque si esté, no estará comprobando adecuadamente con la base de datos?

Soy bastante nueva en general con los dos temas a ver si alguien me pudiera hechar un cable y decirme donde puede ser que este fallando, gracias!

Adjunto el codigo:

```
public class Main {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Validador de empresas");
    frame.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Introduce el nombre de la empresa: ");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 68, 204, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(264, 67, 114, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Validar");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            validar(textField.getText());
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(163, 93, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}

public void validar(String empresa) {
    String formato = "";

    try {
        //se crea la conexion
        Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm_db", "root","");

        //crear objeto statement
        Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();

        //ejecutamos SQL
        ResultSet miConsulta = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM enterprise");

        //recorrer  el resultSet
        while(miConsulta.next()) {
            System.out.println("nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name"));
            if(empresa == miConsulta.getString("name") ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, formato, "La empresa esta en la BD", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.out.println("Esta empresa esta registrada en nuestro base de datos");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, formato, "La empresa no esta en la BD", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        //cerramos la conexion
        miConsulta.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo varios errores en tu codigo

1. Estas cerrando la conexión antes de comparar si la empresa se encuentra en la base de datos.
2. Para comparar cadenas de texto en java se utiliza `equals()` y no `==`.

   Como recomendación te sugiero que crees una variable `boolean` antes del `while` y dentro del while haces la comparación en caso de que exista pones `true` en la variable `boolean` y por ultimo imprimes el mensaje, otra sugerencia que te doy es que hagas la comparación directamente en la base de datos con `SQL`.

Tu codigo tendria que quedar asi:

```
    public void validar(String empresa) {
    String formato = "";

    try {
        //se crea la conexion
        Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebas", "root","");

        //crear objeto statement
        Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();

        //ejecutamos SQL
        ResultSet miConsulta = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM enterprise");

        //crea la variable booleana
        boolean existe = false;
        //recorrer  el resultSet
        while(miConsulta.next()) {
            System.out.println("nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name"));

            if(empresa.equals(miConsulta.getString("name"))) {
             //si la empresa existe marca como true la variable existe
             existe = true;
             //añadimos un break para que salga del bucle cuando encuentre la empresa
             break;
            }
        }
        
        //verifica si la variable existe se encuentra en true
        if(existe) {
            System.out.println("Esta empresa esta registrada en nuestro base de datos");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, formato, "Esta empresa existe en la base de datos: "+ empresa, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("La empresa no esta registrada en la base de datos");
        }

        //cerramos la conexion
        miConsulta.close();
        

    }catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se que tratabas de hacer.. pero tu error esta aca:

```
//recorrer  el resultSet
while(miConsulta.next()) {
    System.out.println("nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name"));
}
//cerramos la conexion
miConsulta.close();
//ERROR ACA
if(empresa == miConsulta.getString("name") ) {
```

Como vas a obtener `miConsulta.getString("name")`, si miConsulta esta cerrado en la linea anterior?

Si lo que querias era saber si una empresa estaba en la DB, en realidad deberias haber ejecutado un query a la DB que te devolviera por ejemplo una cuenta de registros:

```
SELECT count(*) existe
FROM enterprise 
where name = [tu variable aca]
```

Nota: obviamente mejor si lo haces con parametros

Y luego de ejecutar ese query, te fijas si existe trajo un 1 o un 0 y ya solucionas tu problema

---

Si lo queres solucionar con tu codigo sin modificar tu query, seria algo asi:

```
//recorrer  el resultSet
boolean encontre = false;
while(miConsulta.next()) {
    if(empresa == miConsulta.getString("name") ) {
        encontre = true;
    }
}
if (encontre) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, formato, "La empresa esta en la BD", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println("Esta empresa esta registrada en nuestro base de datos");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, formato, "La empresa no esta en la BD", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: hola!! acabo de editar la pregunta, ya que tal vez no explicaba adecuadamente el funcionamiento de mi programa, también he solucionado el error ya saca la ventana, pero ahora no me comprueba adecuadamente que la empresa que le indico está en la BD, ya que siempre indica que no está, y por cada comprobación saca una ventana, supongo que del funcionamiento del while, pero nose como hacerlo mejor.

Comment: No se muy bien como colocar en java el query de forma correcta ya que solo he probado de la forma que he hecho yo, buscando el parametro  por su nombre.

Comment: Pero no estas haciendo lo que te dije en esta respuesta.. fijate que hace tu codigo.. revisa linea por linea lo que viene de la base de datos y muestra carteles por cada comprobacion... deberias hacer lo que te propongo en a respuesta

Comment: si esq mientras me respondias he estado toqueteando el codigo y se me habia quedado así, no se muy bien implementar el query en java como tu me indicas, es que he aprendido esto de forma autodidacta sin que nadie me lo explique y estoy un poco perdida

Comment: ok.. ataquemos los problemas de a uno.. porque si no vas a editar la pregunta con cada problema que tengas.. si es asi, mejor hablarlo en el [chat]

Comment: esta respuesta soluciono el problema original? ahora tu problema es que no sabes construir un query que resuelva esto?

Comment: bueno el problema no era solo el error, mi problema principal es que nose como validar los datos de la BD con la interfaz de Jswing

Comment: PEro eso no es un error.. es un problema de concepto... podrias hacerlo como esta en tu codigo, con algunos cambios sencillos.. espera actualizo la respuesta, pero no toques mas la pregunta.. y para estas cosas mas largas, mejor el [chat]